# will an iphone app built with Base SDK 3.2 be rejected by apple?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios4

I've recently updated xcode to 3.2 and to the iPhone SDK 4.0. I've submuitted the binary and my app is "waiting for review". However, my base SDK was set to iPhone Device 3.2 and I have been reading rumours that apps not submitted with iPhone SDK4.0 wont be approved. Is this correct? My deployment target is 3.0, but BASE SDK is iPHone Device 3.2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see https://developer.apple.com/iphone/checklist/ Apple says:

> All new applications and updates to existing applications submitted to the App Store must be built with iPhone SDK 4.

However I do know of people who have had 3.2-built apps accepted in the past week so it doesn't look like Apple is rejecting apps based on the SDK at the moment.

So if you have already submitted your app, I would wait and see what happens. Otherwise you should compile with the 4.0 SDK.

Comment: Thats the iPhone checklist, you cannot target iPads with 4.0 as they only run 3.2. If you want your able to be able to run on an iPad even in 1x mode you would need a 3.2/4.0 default (remember iPhones dont run 3.2 the run 3.1.3 or 4.0).

Comment: Of course you can build iPad apps with 4.0. The SDK is different from the deployment target. You should always compile apps with the latest SDK and use the deployment target to make them run on earlier OS versions.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine, I submitted an app like this a week ago.

Base SDK 3.2 should be correct if you want you app to be compatible with iPads (they require 3.2).  If I am correct I think you will find that the iPhone will be compiled 4.0.

John.

Comment: Thanks John, is there a way I can confirm this 100%? Otherwise I might have to resubmit the binary as Base SDK 4.0 (deployment 3.0), but that'll mean loss of valuable review days, and I really need this app approved first time round, and would hate to have the app perfect but get rejected for something like this.

Comment: I weighed up how long ago I submitted the app, and the prospect of having to wait an additional 7 days if I left it and got rejected, and decided to reject the binary and reupload with iPhone 4.0. After all, I am not targetting iPad's, so I feel this is the safest route. Thanks.